# Reply to "That was a good show" : "Was it? Really?" Vs "Was it really?"

Tags: questions, punctuation

Same for something like:

"Is he really good?"

"Is he? Really?"

Or

"Is he really?"

Which is the correct answer in such cases?

Comment: I think you mean: *Same for something like: "He is really good."*

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that both constructions are possible.

Which one you choose depends on exactly what you want to say.

> A. That was a good show.
> B. Was it? Really?

Here B responds by asking two questions although they may be largely just polite reactions to A's statement rather than real questions. There might be a pause of several seconds between the two. The **Really** could be followed by either a question mark or an exclamation mark, depending on B's intonation.

> A. That was a good show.
> B. Was it really (a good show)?

Here B responds with a single question although again it may be just a sympathetic reaction to A, or an acknowledgement of A's comment, rather than a real question.

Answer (score 0):

If one asks the question "really?" right after they are told *something is a certain way*, it is likely there is disagreement or at least suspicion regarding the said statement. So in both cases that you have mentioned, it could come across like you don't believe the show was good. However I believe there are nuances:

"Was it?" alone doesn't have an implication of disbelief. It just something to say when you have nothing to say, in order to be polite and keep the conversation going; like, "Oh, was it?".

"Really?" alone works more or less the same.

"Was it? Really?" on the other hand, could sound like you wouldn't expect it to be that way. It sounds more like a real question with the repeating rising intonation, compared to the previous single versions. So to me it sounds like you are open to the idea of the show turning out to be good, even though you hadn't expected it to be.

"Was is really?" is almost always a rhetorical question. I would use this when I have just seen the show and didn't like it. You could say it with a rising tone like a proper question, or with a falling tone like "Was it really." to imply disappointment with the statement. With this one I would be ready to explain why I don't think the show was good.